# How to get the file path location of a .jar dependency?

Tags: gradle

Lets say I have this dependency defined in my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.0"
    classpath "com.opencsv:opencsv:3.1"
}
```

Is there a way for me to get the absolute file path location of the 2 .jar files resulting from the above dependency, as a List object?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following piece of code will do the job:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
   lol
}

dependencies {
    lol "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.0"
    lol "com.opencsv:opencsv:3.1"
}

task printLocations << {
   configurations.lol.files.each { println it }
}
```

Don't know what's your goal but in general that's the way to go.

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy it's just a configuration's name.

Comment: Right, I though so. But why did you name it lol? The difference between custom names and built in keywords is not always clear to beginners

Comment: What about if we need the full path of the *.jar it self ?

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy to make it clear that its a custom name

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can get physical path location from Configurations object. Reference: http://discuss.gradle.org/t/what-is-the-best-way-to-resolve-the-physical-location-of-a-declared-dependency/6999

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it, more explicitly:

```
project.buildscript.configurations.classpath.each {
    String jarName = it.getName();
    print jarName + ":"
}
```

Here is [my build script URL](https://github.com/djangofan/launch-jmeter/blob/master/build.gradle).